# Get Radio Button Value from Complex Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like below. There's some competencies, and each competencies has their value option to be choosed. Each competencies has total which is get from the value*weight value.

How to count the total for each competencies everytime the radio button change using jquery? The total in the right column is count by value from radio button*weight value.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqsxp.png)

Table Format:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Competencies</th>
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>Score Definition</th>
      <th>Tolerance Scale</th>
      <th>Standard Scale</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="competency-lists">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">Faith<br><br><span class="competencydefinition"></span></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="0" checked="true"> 0 </td>
      <td class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 0
      </td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="minvalue-1">2</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="maxvalue-1">2</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="weightvalue-1">7</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="totalcompetency-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="1"> 1</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 1
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="2"> 2</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 2
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="3"> 3</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 3
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="4"> 4</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 4
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="5"> 5</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 5</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">Opennes<br><br></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="0" checked="true"> 0 </td>
      <td class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 0 </td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="minvalue-2">1</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="maxvalue-2">2</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="weightvalue-2">7</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="totalcompetency-2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="1"> 1</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 1

</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="2"> 2</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 2
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="3"> 3</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 3
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="4"> 4</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 4
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="5"> 5</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 5
</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok.. So what you've tried so far? and what is the `weight` value you mentioned about?

Comment: Consider `<select>` elements instead of radio groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see that you have id number `1`, `2` and so on common for each `weightvalue`, `radio` and  `totalcompetency`. Thus, you can set up your logic in such a way that you can detect the `weight` from each row and calculate `total` for each row uniquely when the `radio` button is selected by using that id number. You can understand that very well by looking at the below example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var idNum = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
  var weight = $('#weightvalue-'+idNum).text();
  var total = parseInt(val) * parseInt(weight);
  $('#totalcompetency-'+idNum).text(total);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<table border='1' class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Competencies</th>
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>Score Definition</th>
      <th>Tolerance Scale</th>
      <th>Standard Scale</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="competency-lists">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">Faith<br><br><span class="competencydefinition"></span></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="0" checked="true"> 0 </td>
      <td class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 0
      </td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="minvalue-1">2</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="maxvalue-1">2</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="weightvalue-1">7</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="totalcompetency-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="1"> 1</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 1
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="2"> 2</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 2
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="3"> 3</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 3
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="4"> 4</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 4
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Faith" id="radio-1" value="5"> 5</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 5</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">Opennes<br><br></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="0" checked="true"> 0 </td>
      <td class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 0 </td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="minvalue-2">1</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="maxvalue-2">2</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="weightvalue-2">7</td>
      <td rowspan="6" id="totalcompetency-2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="1"> 1</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 1

</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="2"> 2</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 2
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="3"> 3</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 3
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="4"> 4</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 4
</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="Opennes" id="radio-2" value="5"> 5</td>
      <td class="competencydefinition"><span class="competencydefinition">Long Desc of Value 5
</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```